# Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address

Tags: heroku

Everybody,

I get an error when I run this command: "git push heroku master". The error log shows the following:

```
$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.156' to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 209 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected

To git@heroku.com:simple-earth-536.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@app_name.git'
```

Any idea what could cause this? I welcome any suggestions, thanks all.

Comment: Follow this article from Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you are not in a rails application, such as if you are not in the correct directory.

Make sure you are actually in your apps directory.

```
rails myapp
cd myapp
```

This is the flow you should go through"

```
rails new_app
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'master'
heroku create
git push heroku
```

Comment: NP, Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: How to update the app to heroku when i fix my code in local repository ?

Comment: `git push heroku` or `git push heroku master`

Comment: 'git push heroku master' this command works fine,  this 'git push heroku' get me some warning and a error message on custom page of heroku, that message like this                                      'The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
'

Comment: `heroku create`
`git push heroku
`, about this command , i also need to add the 'master' keyword at last.